# Background wont reach bottom of page

Tags: css

I have a white container on top of the bg but it stops even though min-height is set as 100%, heres the CSS for this container and in bottom I have included image of what happens when I scroll to the bottom:
Container where post is:
Yellow Bg:

```
               .home-body {
                background-color:#EAC117;
                height: 100%;

            .home-main-content {
            width:800px;
            min-height: 100%;
            position:absolute;
            overflow:hidden;
            margin-left:56.5%;
            left:-500px;
            top:51px;
            border-left:1px solid black;
            border-right:1px solid black;
            background-color:#fff;
            background-repeat:repeat-y;



            .home-post-echoed-container {
            width:400px;
            position:absolute;
            margin-left:50%;
            left:-200px;
            top:200px;
            overflow:hidden;
            }
            .home-echoed-posts {
            width:600px;
            overflow:hidden;
            left:-98px;
            position:relative;
            background-color:#fff;
            margin-bottom:-5px;
            border-top:1px solid;color:#0a527e;
            border-left:1px solid;color:#0a527e;
            border-right:1px solid;color:#0a527e;
            }
            .home-echoed-posts-post {
            margin:10px;
            color:black;
            }
            .home-echoed-posts-email {
            margin:10px;
            color:black;
            }
            .home-echoed-posts-date {
            margin:10px;
            color:black;
                            }
```

[image: This is what happens when end of bg is cleared]

Comment: Post a sample version on [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing it wrong.

To center something you should use (instead of absolute positioning):

```
.foobar{
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 800px;
}
```

As for "why comments are not expanding the container",  it is hard to guess without code, but there are two reasonable possibilities: **positioning** or **floats**. There nothing i can do about it. But if they are floated, then easies is to have container with following css:

```
.container{
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

It is a bit counter-intuitive, but works like charm. You can read more about it [**here**](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/).

Update: and read [**this article**](http://colinaarts.com/articles/float-containment/) too.

**Update 2**:

Looks like it is the worts case scenario. You are using positioning .. for everything. YOu really need to learn how to use floats.

```
.home-post-echoed-container {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 200px; // im guessing what top:200px was doing
    overflow:hidden;
}
.home-echoed-posts {
    width:600px;
    float: left;
    background: #fff;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    border: 1px solid #0a527e;
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

Something like this. But I'm really just guessing.

Comment: I have updated question if that helps, and thank you, I will read that now.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked, white background stretches to bottom.
Except one thing, now the container gets cut off slightly at the right, might know whats wrong?

Comment: @checkit923 , the point here is : stop using absolute positioning for simple layout. It has very specific use-cases, when using it is a good idea. In normal situation position just "takes out" the element of pageflow (it becomes unable to affect others). Instead you should extensively experiment with `float` properties. Learn how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

```
html, body 
{
    height:100%;
}
```

Make sure you include that in the top of your CSS script, else setting `.home-main-content` to `min-height:100%;` won't work, because to CSS, if undefined elsewhere, `100%` is simply the height of the current div.

Also ensure that you have that same property set if your `.home-main-content` is surrounded by another div.

Comment: Okay, the only thing behind that white container is the yellow bg, and its set at height 100%, so I have to put that also for whats on top of the white container?

Comment: Have you ensured that the first block of code, for `html, body` has been inserted?