# How do I make a child div match the height of scrolling parent?

Tags: html, css, scroll, formatting, overflow

How can I make a div and nested divs extend down to the full height of the screen with scrolling on the body?

Link to a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qsczjd01/

CSS:

```
#megaAll{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: gray;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

I need #megaAll (gray), #megaMain(pink), and #contentContainer to extend all the way down the page, but it seems unable to extend to the full height because of the scrolling on the body. I need the scrolling on the body and fixed sidebar on the right to remain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! I changed my divs from using position: absolute, and then 0px all around, to using static positioning with margins at 0px.

New example div:

```
#megaAll{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11068062/5879337

Answer (score 0):

Extending them down is just height:auto; which need not to be mentioned as it is default. Whatever will be the height of your body, it will auto adjust it all over the page.
"sidebar on the right to remain" means fixed, this will work if I got you right.

> position: fixed;

Comment: Yes I have my sidebar fixed already, I just need any solution to not change that. height: auto does not automatically make a div fill its parent div but rather just big enough to fit padding and content.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
position: fixed;
```

instead. This will position the element fixed in the window, rather than fixed within the body element.

Comment: But then it doesn't scroll and the content is cut off.